# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'actstream'

Tags: python, django, mayanedms

want to setup Mayan-EDMS framework to my laptop I read a lot of document but still I face problem to run this server on my laptop. I need someone who have a good experience and work on this platforms.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.